# How can I resolve my project dependency issue?

Tags: c#, interface

I have 3 projects:

- **GameEngine.Rendering**

  - Contains interfaces and abstract classes for other projects to implement and create a rendering API abstraction layer.
- **GameEngine.Rendering.OpenGL4**

  - An OpenGL 4.0 implementation of the interfaces.
- **GameEngine.Rendering.Direct3D11**

  - A Direct3D 11 implementation of the interfaces.

One interface of the **GameEngine.Rendering** project looks like this:

```cs
public interface IRenderContext
{
    void SwapBuffers();
}
```

The OpenGL 4.0 implementation of this interface requires a `IWindowInfo` interface as a parameter to be created, whereas the Direct3D 11 implementation does not. The Direct3D 11 implementation requires an `IntPtr` handle to a window.

I didn't think this would be to much of an issue until I wanted to make creating a render context easy and painless:

```cs
var renderContext = CreateRenderContext(DriverType.Direct3D11, windowHandle);
```

The only solution I thought of was in the **GameEngine.Rendering** project to create a struct like so, that implements `IWindowInfo`:

```cs
public struct RenderContextInfo : IWindowInfo
{
    public IntPtr OutputHandle { get; set; }
}
```

However, it's not exactly a good design choice as I'd rather the **GameEngine.Rendering** project not know anything about any implementations.

I was just wondering what my options are with how to solve this? Is there some fancy trick where I can maybe instantiate an `IWindowInfo` interface?

Comment: Doesn't IWindowInfo expose a [WindowHandle that is an IntPtr](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_IWindowInfo_WindowHandle.htm)? If so, your API should simply accept an IWindowHandle as an argument. The implementation can then decide to pass the entire interface (to OpenGL) or just pass the IntPtr (if it's D3D).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to resolve this problem is to pass to your **CreateRenderContext** an `IntPtr` handle to a window, and in your **GameEngine.Rendering.Direct3D11** project create an instance of `RenderContextInfo` and use it as you need with `OpenTK` library.
In this case, your abstraction will not know anything about implementations.